# SQL - Запрос. Для каждого читателя посчитать, сколько раз он первым брал любую книгу

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу: Для каждого читателя посчитать, сколько раз он первым брал любую книгу. Если гость не брал книг - вывести 0. Вывести фамилию читателя и посчитанное значение. Последний столбец назвать Количество. Информацию отсортировать сначала по убыванию количества, а затем по фамилии читателя в алфавитном порядке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этапе соединения запросов в табличное выражение я поплыл и никак не могу понять как правильно написать на MySQL. Это мое не рабочее табличное выражение:

```
WITH GET_DATES1(book_id, MIN_borrow_date) AS (
    SELECT book_id
         , MIN(borrow_date)
    FROM book_reader   
    GROUP BY 1
),
GET_DATES2(reader_id) AS (
    SELECT reader_id
    FROM book_reader
    INNER JOIN GET_DATES1 USING(book_id) 
        AND book_reader.borrow_date = GET_DATES1.MIN_borrow_date
) 
SELECT reader_name
     , COUNT(borrow_date) AS Количество   
FROM reader  
LEFT JOIN GET_DATES2 USING(reader_id) 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: `count(reader_id)` таки может?

Comment: зы: не используйте номера столбцов в группировках; USING крайне на любителя. Давайте таблицам адекватные имена и краткие алиасы.

Comment: Переделайте Ваш пример, как указал @teran. Например USING(..) AND ... - не совмещаются. Если исправите синтаксические ошибки, заодно поправите и семантические. Например, count(borrow_date) - нет такой колонки в этом месте. Должно быть count(GET_DATES2.reader_id). Группировка по reader_name - засада) Могут быть однофамильцы. В тестовом задании такие наверняка есть.

Comment: поправил, но результат не верный)) блин

Answer (score 1):

Поправил вот так, но результат не верный :) блин

```
WITH GET_DATES1(reader_name, book_id, Количество) 
AS (SELECT reader_name, book_id, MIN(borrow_date) AS Количество
FROM book_reader
RIGHT JOIN reader ON book_reader.reader_id = reader.reader_id
GROUP BY reader_name, book_id)
SELECT reader_name, COUNT(Количество) AS Количество   
FROM GET_DATES1
GROUP BY reader_name
ORDER BY Количество DESC, reader_name;
```

Comment: Вы здесь посчитали, сколько раз каждый читатель брал книги вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример

```
-- test data
create table reader(reader_id int,reader_name varchar(10));
insert into reader values
 (1001,'Name1001')
,(1002,'Name1002')
,(1003,'Name100x')
,(1004,'Name100x')
;
create table book_reader(book_reader_id int, book_id int,reader_id int
  ,borrow_date date,return_date date);
insert into book_reader values
 (1,101,1001,'2023-01-01','2023-01-05')
,(2,101,1002,'2023-01-06','2023-01-12')
,(3,102,1003,'2023-01-06','2023-01-12')
;
-- query
with rnk as(
  select *
       -- rn=1 - первый раз взяли книгу эту книгу (для каждого book_id)
    ,row_number()over(partition by book_id order by borrow_date)rn
  from book_reader
 )
,Book1Cnt as(
select reader_id
     -- если rn=1  - этот читатель первым взял книгу (точнее - раньше всех)
  ,sum(case when rn=1 then 1 else 0 end) cnt
 from rnk
 group by reader_id
 )
 select reader.reader_id,reader_name,coalesce(cnt,0) cnt
 from reader -- нужны все читатели, бравшие или не бравшие книги
 left join Book1Cnt on Book1Cnt.reader_id=reader.reader_id
 ;
```

Результат на тестовых данных

| reader_id | reader_name | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Name1001 | 1 |
| 1002 | Name1002 | 0 |
| 1003 | Name100x | 1 |
| 1004 | Name100x | 0 |

[Пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/HhV2pUeD)

Ваш первоначальный вариант должен выглядеть примерно так

```
WITH GET_DATES1(book_id, MIN_borrow_date) AS (
    SELECT book_id,MIN(borrow_date) MIN_borrow_date
    FROM book_reader   
    GROUP BY book_id
),
GET_DATES2(reader_id) AS (
    SELECT reader_id
    FROM book_reader
    INNER JOIN GET_DATES1 on book_reader.book_id=GET_DATES1.book_id
        AND book_reader.borrow_date = GET_DATES1.MIN_borrow_date
) 
SELECT min(reader_name) as reader_name
     , COUNT(GET_DATES2.reader_id) AS Количество   
FROM reader  
LEFT JOIN GET_DATES2 on GET_DATES2.reader_id=reader.reader_id
GROUP BY reader.reader_id;
```

Повторю вслед за @teran, применение алиасов и правильным наименованием промежуточных и вспомогательных объектов полезно.
Назовите, `GET_DATES` - например `First_book_borrow_dates` и алиас `fbbd` или другое понятное Вам и другим читателям наименование.